# How to post only text on facebook wall with Facebook SDK 4.+

Tags: android, facebook

I am using facebook SDK newest (v 4.15)

```
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
```

I want to post a text to my wall without dialog showing. I found a class with name **ShareApi** can help me do this.

```
private void publish() {

        ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentTitle("title example")
                .setContentDescription("Des example")
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("www.google.com"))
                .build();

        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                .setBitmap(image)
                .setCaption("Binh test!")
                .build();
        SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                .addPhoto(photo)
                .build();


        ShareFeedContent shareFeedContent = new ShareFeedContent.Builder()
                .setLinkName("link name example")
                .setLink("www.google.com")
                .setLinkCaption("Google")
                .build();

        //ShareApi.share(linkContent, shareResult); // worked well
        //ShareApi.share(photoContent, shareResult); // worked well
        ShareApi.share(shareFeedContent, shareResult); // nothing call back from facebook
}


FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result> shareResult = new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
            LogUtil.debug(CLASS_NAME + " Share success");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            LogUtil.debug(CLASS_NAME + " onCancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            LogUtil.debug(CLASS_NAME + " Share error: " + e.toString());
        }
    };
```

After tried, I can post successfully a link or a photo to my wall.

**My expect, I only want to post a text without link or photo**

I tried something below :

**1. Share LinkContent**

I try to change link URL to empty but Facebook do not accept this parameter as empty.

```
ShareLinkContent linkContent = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                    .setContentTitle("title example")
                    .setContentDescription("Des example")
                    .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("")) // empty Url
                    .build();
```

**2. PhotoContent**

I set bitmap parameter is null but also not accept from facebook

```
SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(null)
                    .setCaption("Caption test!")
                    .build();
            SharePhotoContent photoContent = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                    .addPhoto(photo)
                    .build();
```

**3. ShareFeedContent**

Nothing response.

```
ShareFeedContent shareFeedContent = new ShareFeedContent.Builder()
                .setLinkName("link name example")
                .setLink("www.google.com")
                .setLinkCaption("Google")
                .build();
```

Comment: I think its not possible to post only text.your  Share LinkContent is used to display text in setContentdescription as a  dynamic text.

Comment: @Naruto , if it is not possible, this is a missing case from Facebook

Comment: Check this one.may be it will help you http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/facebook-sharing-in-android/

Comment: @Naruto : It use a dialog to post message and it is not as my expect

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?